# How to count "|" in a csv file through awk command?

Tags: bash, awk, count

I have a file as below

```
"a"|"a|b|c|d"|"as|ds"
```

I want to count total number of "|" to get the exact column count.

Comment: Do you mean you want `"|"` with double quotes around to be counted?

Comment: yes, exactly. Do u have any idea ?

Comment: What is the expected output in the above example? 3?

Comment: Question is unclear until you provide your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{print gsub(/\"\|\"/,"&",$0)}' input.txt
```

Prints number of substitutions of `"|"` i.e count of it, so

```
awk '{print gsub(/\"\|\"/,"&",$0) +1 }' input.txt
```

Will be number of columns.

`"&"` means substitute the matched string with itself, i.e no change.

---

**EDIT**

Or use

```
awk -F'["][|]["]' '{print NF}' input.txt
```

Which prints number of columns and this

```
awk -F'["][|]["]' '{print NF-1}' input.txt
```

is the number of `"|"`

Comment: Sorry, this won't help

Comment: @user3635916, I have edited the answer, It seems working, but it maybe not the best way.

Answer (score 3):

`awk -F'"[|]"' '{print NF}'`

will return the number of columns (NF is a built in variable returning the number of fields)

edit: surround the pipe with [] to escape it and it works correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If you have `gnu awk` version 4+, you can use `FPAT` to specify how the data looks like, and then count.

```
echo '"a"|"a|b|c|d"|"as|ds"' | awk '{print NF}' FPAT='"([a-z]+[|]*)+"'
3
```

To see the column:

```
echo '"a"|"a|b|c|d"|"as|ds"' | awk '{print "1="$1,"2="$2,"3="$3}' FPAT='"([a-z]+[|]*)+"'
1="a" 2="a|b|c|d" 3="as|ds"
```

But since `FS` works, I would have used `awk -F'"[|]"' '{print NF}'`

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following perl script:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Text::CSV;


my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ sep_char => '|' });

while (<>) {
   $csv->parse($_);
   my @fields = $csv->fields();
   print scalar @fields,"\n";
}
```

Comment: @user3635916, if that's a requirement, you need to specify that in the question, or remove all tags except [tag:awk]